# Wine entries persist after uninstall wine

Tags: 12.04, unity, wine, zeitgeist

I updated to 12.04 from 11.10 recently and I had a few problems I solved without much effort.

But one thing is still bothering me. I uninstalled Wine (and removed the `.wine` directory) but the entries in the zeitgeist still appear.

Does anyone know how delete it?

Answer (score 3):

The following did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine1.4-dbg wine1.4-common wine1.4-amd64 wine1.4-dev winetricks wine1.4-i386
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot and be wine free.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gksu nautilus` to delete the directory. And try to restart your system, to make sure that the entries persist or not.

Comment: I would avoid deleting things just yet. Move them to an innocuous folder and be ready to move them back if there is an issue.